# Facebook web sdk on reload page status unknown even if user is logged in

Tags: javascript, reactjs, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am new to the react, Here I have a requirement where I can log in facebook so I am using followig,

```
 <script>
      window._onFacebook = new Promise((res, rej) => {
          window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
            FB.init({
              appId: 'id',
              autoLogAppEvents: true,
              xfbml: true,
              version: 'v5.0',
              status: true
            });
            console.log('Initialized facebook SDK');
            res(FB);
          };
        });

    </script>
    <script async defer src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js"></script>
```

for logging in,

function facebookAPI() {
    const returnVal = {};
    // Note - we wait till the facebook sdk is loaded in the app usng promises (see index.html)
    const facebookPromise = window._onFacebook;

```
returnVal.login = function(callback) {
  facebookPromise.then(FB => {
    FB && FB.login(callback , { scope: ['user_photos', 'user_location'] });
  });
};
```

then for status

```
 returnVal.checkLoginStatus = function(callback) {
      facebookPromise.then(FB => {
        FB && FB.getLoginStatus(callback, true);
      });
    };
```

Now, In didupdate.

```
componentDidMount() {
    if (localStorage.getItem('accessToken')) {
      this.setState({ authenticated: true });
    }

    facebookAPI.checkLoginStatus(response => {
      // Here I am getting status UNKNOWN even if user is logged in. 
      if (response.status !== 'connected') {
        // login error - redirect to login
        this.props.history.push('/login');
      }
    });
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    const { isLoggedIn } = this.props;
    if (isLoggedIn && isLoggedIn !== prevProps.isLoggedIn) {
      // fetch user data like albums, etc
      facebookAPI.getAlbums(response => {
        const albums = response.albums || { data: [] };
        this.props.gotUserData(albums.data);

        facebookAPI.getUserProfile(response => {
          this.props.gotUserProfile(response);
          this.props.history.push('/alb');
        });
      });
    }
```

So, in Here on reload of the page it should be given as a logged in state. it is giving me unknown. can any one help me with this ?
      }